# C# Serial data is split into random amounts, tried to find carriage return with no luck

Tags: c#, arduino

Hello i have made a C# App to read the Serial data from my Arduino, If and only if i use Serial.println on my Arduino when sending the data does my App get all the data correctly thanks to using ReadLine(), because of the \n\r the Arduino attaches with printline.

But if i just send the data normally from my Arduino using Serial.print which has no \n and thus use ReadExisting(), i am unable to get all the text at once i get it in random amounts maybe too halves of the stream or just 2 characters then 10 and 6, its completely random. I have tried to place the text in a char array and use Contains or EndsWith and readChar and readByte, to look for the "null or CR or ETX or EOT" with no luck. [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

What can i do to detect the end of the stream, please any guidance is welcome.

EDIT:: after some thought i see that even though the data is split randomly using `port.ReadExisting()` the missing parts to the text come very soon after, much less than the gap between each transmission by the Arduino which is 1 second at the moment. so i am going to try and concatenate them together if the time for the next packet is close.

here's a simple log i made for each part of the text received, NOTE i have it as a csv format for now just to test my find functions. it is not always that format.

```
Current mills: 1532199847091 ms   <=================================== START OF PROGRAM ON ARDUINO currentMills - previousMills, .....previousMills = currentMills 
elapsed time: 1532199847091 ms
receviedText: Starting
,test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7


Current mills: 1532199848085 ms
elapsed time: 994 ms
receviedText: ,test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7


Current mills: 1532199849068 ms
elapsed time: 983 ms
receviedText: ,test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,t

Current mills: 1532199849072 ms
elapsed time: 4 ms
receviedText: est6,test7


Current mills: 1532199850068 ms
elapsed time: 996 ms
receviedText: ,test1,test2

Current mills: 1532199850072 ms
elapsed time: 4 ms
receviedText: ,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7


Current mills: 1532199851071 ms
elapsed time: 999 ms
receviedText: ,test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,te

Current mills: 1532199851075 ms
elapsed time: 4 ms
receviedText: st7


Current mills: 1532199852070 ms
elapsed time: 995 ms
receviedText: ,test1,test2,test3,

Current mills: 1532199852074 ms
elapsed time: 4 ms
receviedText: test4,test5,test6,test7


Current mills: 1532199853074 ms
elapsed time: 1000 ms
receviedText: ,test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7


Current mills: 1532199854073 ms
elapsed time: 999 ms
receviedText: ,test1,test2,test3,test4,t

Current mills: 1532199854077 ms
elapsed time: 4 ms
receviedText: est5,test6,test7


Current mills: 1532199855072 ms
elapsed time: 995 ms
receviedText: ,test1

Current mills: 1532199855077 ms
elapsed time: 5 ms
receviedText: ,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7


Current mills: 1532199856076 ms
elapsed time: 999 ms
receviedText: ,test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,te

Current mills: 1532199856080 ms
elapsed time: 4 ms
receviedText: st6,test7


Current mills: 1532199857075 ms
elapsed time: 995 ms
receviedText: ,test1,test2,

Current mills: 1532199857079 ms
elapsed time: 4 ms
receviedText: test3,test4,test5,test6,test7


Current mills: 1532199858079 ms
elapsed time: 1000 ms
receviedText: ,test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,tes

Current mills: 1532199858082 ms
elapsed time: 3 ms
receviedText: t7


Current mills: 1532199859078 ms
elapsed time: 996 ms
receviedText: ,test1,test2,test3,t

Current mills: 1532199859082 ms
elapsed time: 4 ms
receviedText: est4,test5,test6,test7


Current mills: 1532199860081 ms
elapsed time: 999 ms
receviedText: ,test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7


Current mills: 1532199861081 ms
elapsed time: 1000 ms
receviedText: ,test1,test2,test3,test4,te

Current mills: 1532199861085 ms
elapsed time: 4 ms
receviedText: st5,test6,test7


Current mills: 1532199862080 ms
elapsed time: 995 ms
receviedText: ,test1

Current mills: 1532199862084 ms
elapsed time: 4 ms
receviedText: ,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7


Current mills: 1532199863083 ms
elapsed time: 999 ms
receviedText: ,test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,tes

Current mills: 1532199863087 ms
elapsed time: 4 ms
receviedText: t6,test7


Current mills: 1532199864083 ms
elapsed time: 996 ms
receviedText: ,test1,test2,t

Current mills: 1532199864087 ms
elapsed time: 4 ms
receviedText: est3,test4,test5,test6,test7


Current mills: 1532199865086 ms
elapsed time: 999 ms
receviedText: ,test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test

Current mills: 1532199865090 ms
elapsed time: 4 ms
receviedText: 7


Current mills: 1532199866085 ms
elapsed time: 995 ms
receviedText: ,test1,test2,test3,te

Current mills: 1532199866089 ms
elapsed time: 4 ms
receviedText: st4,test5,test6,test7


Current mills: 1532199867086 ms
elapsed time: 997 ms
receviedText: ,

Current mills: 1532199867090 ms
elapsed time: 4 ms
receviedText: test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7


Current mills: 1532199868089 ms
elapsed time: 999 ms
receviedText: ,test1,test2,test3,test4,tes

Current mills: 1532199868093 ms
elapsed time: 4 ms
receviedText: t5,test6,test7


Current mills: 1532199869088 ms
elapsed time: 995 ms
receviedText: ,test1,t

Current mills: 1532199869092 ms
elapsed time: 4 ms
receviedText: est2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7


Current mills: 1532199870092 ms
elapsed time: 1000 ms
receviedText: ,test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test

Current mills: 1532199870096 ms
elapsed time: 4 ms
receviedText: 6,test7


Current mills: 1532199871091 ms
elapsed time: 995 ms
receviedText: ,test1,test2,te

Current mills: 1532199871095 ms
elapsed time: 4 ms
receviedText: st3,test4,test5,test6,test7


Current mills: 1532199872095 ms
elapsed time: 1000 ms
receviedText: ,test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7

Current mills: 1532199872098 ms
elapsed time: 3 ms
receviedText: 


Current mills: 1532199873094 ms
elapsed time: 996 ms
receviedText: ,test1,test2,test3,tes

Current mills: 1532199873098 ms
elapsed time: 4 ms
receviedText: t4,test5,test6,test7


Current mills: 1532199874093 ms
elapsed time: 995 ms
receviedText: ,

Current mills: 1532199874097 ms
elapsed time: 4 ms
receviedText: test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7


Current mills: 1532199875098 ms
elapsed time: 1001 ms
receviedText: ,test1,test2,test3,test4,test

Current mills: 1532199875101 ms
elapsed time: 3 ms
receviedText: 5,test6,test7


Current mills: 1532199876096 ms
elapsed time: 995 ms
receviedText: ,test1,te

Current mills: 1532199876100 ms
elapsed time: 4 ms
receviedText: st2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7


Current mills: 1532199877099 ms
elapsed time: 999 ms
receviedText: ,test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6

Current mills: 1532199877103 ms
elapsed time: 4 ms
receviedText: ,test7
```